# Not a knapsack or bin algorithm

Tags: optimization, packing, knapsack-problem

I need to find a combination of rectangles that will maximize the use of the area of a circle.  The difference between my situation and the classic problems is I have a set of rectangles I **CAN** use, and a subset of those rectangles I **MUST** use.

By way of an analogy:  Think of an end of a log and list of board sizes.  I can cut 2x4s, 2x6s and 2x8s and 2x10 from a log but I must cut at least two 2x4s and one 2x8.

As I understand it, my particular variation is mildly different than other packing optimizations.  Thanks in advance for any insight on how I might adapt existing algorithms to solve this problem.

NCDiesel

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty hard problem, even with squares instead of rectangles.

Here's an idea. Approach it as an knapsack-Integer-Program, which can give you some insights into the solution. (By definition it won't give you the optimal solution.)

#### IP Formulation Heuristic

```
Say you have a total of n rectangles, r1, r2, r3, ..., rn
Let the area of each rectangle be a1, a2, a3, ..., an
Let the area of the large circle you are given be *A*
```

**Decision Variable**

```
Xi = 1 if rectangle i is selected. 0 otherwise.
```

**Objective**

```
 Minimize [A - Sum_over_i (ai * Xi)]
```

Subject to:

```
 Sum_over_i (ai x Xi) <= A # Area_limit constraint
 Xk = 1 for each rectangle k that has to be selected
```

You can solve this using any solver.

Now, the reason this is a heuristic is that this solution totally ignores the arrangement of the rectangles inside the circle. It also ends up "cutting" rectangles into smaller pieces to fit inside the circle. (That is why the Area_limit constraint is a weak bound.)

#### Relevant Reference

[This Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/is-there-an-algorithm-out-there-that-will-show-you-how-to-fit-the-most-rectangle) question addresses the "classic" version of it.
And [you can look at the link](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/) provided as comments in there, for several clever solutions involving squares of the same size packed inside a circle.